# MVC 4 Area Register Sorting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, area

In MVC routing I have a problem.

In basic routing you can simply sort routes by writing them in order you wish. Like below :

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new [] {"SampleApp.UI.Web.Controllers"}
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "CompanyRoute",
            "{Company_url}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "SampleApp.UI.Web.Controllers" }
        );
```

What about areas ?

In a spesific situation I need to register one of my areas before other one. 
How can I sort area routes ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've figured out with the help of disassembler:

```
internal static void RegisterAllAreas(RouteCollection routes, IBuildManager buildManager, object state) {
    List<Type> areaRegistrationTypes = TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies(_typeCacheName, IsAreaRegistrationType, buildManager);
    foreach (Type areaRegistrationType in areaRegistrationTypes) { 
        AreaRegistration registration = (AreaRegistration)Activator.CreateInstance(areaRegistrationType);
        registration.CreateContextAndRegister(routes, state); 
    } 
}
```

This is a method of an abstract class `AreaRegistration` where all your custom area registration classes are called. As you can see, there is no ordering. Deeper in the `TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies` method no ordering either.

I can't see any way to use `AreaRegistration` class for orderable areas registration. The class hasn't any extension point which can be used for the purpose.